# How can I create a local alias for a variable?

Tags: c#, .net

There's a constant `OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength` which I use a lot in this particular scope, and to make my code more compact and descriptive I want to do

```
int linelen = OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength;
```

except I want `linelen` to be a reference to `OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength`, not a copy of its value. I.e., I want to do the equivalent of

```
int * linelenptr = &OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength;
```

in C/C++;

I realize that since `linelen` is just an `int`, this doesn't save any memory; like I said, it's for the mere purpose of compactness and readability.

Comment: Implement a dependent property, like, int LineLen { get { return OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength; } }

Comment: Since it's a constant, why do you need a reference to it?

Comment: David has a good point. Why do you need a reference, if the value is constant?

Comment: Like I said, I don't NEED a reference, but I WANT one

Comment: He does not want a reference, He just does not want to write OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength everywhere. Am I correct?

Comment: Offtopic: _outputMaxLength name suggests it's a private variable. Use OutputMaxLength

Comment: @user5572578, why do you want one?

Comment: if your constant is not marked as ``const`` nor ``readonly`` you can directly insert your (slightly adjusted) c++ code as: ``unsafe { fixed(int* linelenptr = &OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength) { /*``...``*/ } }``

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, if it's not marked as `const` or `readonly`, then it's not a constant!

Comment: @DavidArno I know that, I just felt the need to add that for Paweł Sołtysiak... and ``int Constant { get { return 42; } }`` could be considered a constant ;)

Answer (score 4):

As **@OguzOguz** suggested, you will need to use a `Property` for this:

```
int LineLen { get { return OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength; } }
```

Everytime you use `LineLen`, the `get` will be called to retrieve the latest value.

Comment: And when compiled, the property will look like (if decompiled) int LineLen { get { return 1024; } } since the constant will be inlined by the compiler. :) LOL

Comment: Indeed, this also reduced the need for a 'forwarding property' if the value never changes.

Answer (score 4):

How about a shortcut lambda:

```
Func<int> LineLen = () => OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength;
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this one over the property suggestion? Because it is just Linq? Please enlight me.. (I mean it. If there is an advantage, I should know)

Comment: @OguzOzgul It can be used locally, is shorter and clearer.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman, it's only shorter if C# 6 syntax isn't used for the property. If it is, the property becomes `int LineLen => OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength;`, which is even shorter than

Comment: @DavidArno As it is, it already is shorter, plus the code line of the property solution lacks a visibility specification.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: A bit more info here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/func-generic-delegate-in-C-Sharp/. I wasn't suggesting this was an improvement over a property - just an alternative - a bit like a local method.

Comment: Ok so, here are the results from a very simple benchmark, with 10 million executions, the property getter get_LineLenDB() completed in 3,5822 ms, while the Linq method access get_LineLenLQ() completed in 39,9968 ms. Can share the source code.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: So we have two possible solutions & a benchmark in the event 10 million executions are being performed. Each has it's benefits. With the property, OutputFormatter would need to be declared as a member of the class (which maybe it is), with the Func delegate OutputFormatter only needs to be within scope, so could be a local variable.

Comment: I am not comparing two solutions, I just want to make sure that we know how it works behind the scenes, and not proposing an alternative solution just because it works. The lambda expressions have a significant overhead in terms of both the number of types of our assembly (they create classes) and thus also execute more CPU cycles for this very simple operation of returning a constant value which will be inlined by the compiler anyway. No offense, but lambda expressions in this particular case would be the last thing that I would consider. And may be it's just me thinking that way.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: your solution is good & I was going to propose both - but  you & RvdK replied before I did, so I didn't repeat a solution. I know lambda expressions are slow - but I thought it still worth presenting the OP with that solution as an alternative. From my point of view, if OutputFormatter was a local variable & not being used in a long loop, then I would not consider refactoring the code to give it greater scope than necessary just to save a few clock cycles - I would aim to keep all references local - but I would be happy just to use OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength as is anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The lambda expression is a good solution for the local scope by the way. Frankly, I can't think of another way except getting the pointer to the constant value in a fixed block in an unsafe context which would be very extreme for a simple task like this.